# robotic arm DOF

Tags: dynamics

I'm working on an assignment and was wondering aobut the degrees of freedom this system has.
The generalized coordinates are: 
$\underline{q}:$
\begin{bmatrix}
x  \\
\theta_{1}  \\
\theta_{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
A revolute joint connects both rods. Furthermore, there is a horizontal actuation force $F_{1}$ in the revolute joint and a vertical actuation force $F_{2}$ in $CM_{1}$

I know that there are 2 bodies so 6 DOF in total.
The revolute joint constraints 2 DOF, and both sliders also constrain 1 DOF each. The actuation focres also remove 1 DOF each. which means that the total number of DOF is $0$. Is this correct?

I'm not sure what the spring at the bottom does.

Thanks in advance for any help[image]

Answer (score 3):

The system has 2 DOF!
Your assumption *The actuation focres also remove 1 DOF each.* is wrong.

Generally you can always use a simple proof about the DOF.
In your system you have 3 generalized coordinates. If you fix one of them (e.g. the $x-$coordinate) you can still move the joint via $F_1$. The angles $\theta_1, \theta_2$ would change then.
If you fix another coordinate, lets say $x$ and $\theta_1$ you will not be able to move anything in the system anymore. Therefore the system has 2 degrees of freedom.